# Webpack cannot always resolve the TS loader

Tags: node.js, webpack, ts-loader

This is my original webpack config file, consisting of two different configurations which both are used:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
module.exports = [{
  entry: __dirname + '/src/browser/main',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist/browser',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts'] // '' is needed to find modules like "jquery"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts'
      }
    ]
  }
}, {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', __dirname + '/src/app/browser/app'],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist/app/browser',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    root: ['./node_modules', './src'],
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts'] // '' is needed to find modules like "jquery"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css!sass')
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.css')
  ]
}]
```

Even though all my imports are accepted by, for instance, Atom (text editor with TypeScript plugin), currently only the following alternative works:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
module.exports = [{
  entry: __dirname + '/src/browser/main',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist/browser',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts'] // '' is needed to find modules like "jquery"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts'
      }
    ]
  }
}, {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', __dirname + '/src/app/browser/app'],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist/app/browser',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    root: ['./node_modules', './src'],
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts'] // '' is needed to find modules like "jquery"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: require.resolve('ts-loader')
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css!sass')
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.css')
  ]
}]
```

(note the `require.resolve('ts-loader')`)

As you can see, in the first config `'ts'` is still present (since it still works), while in the second one I needed to replace it by `require.resolve('ts-loader')`. Now I try to find the reason for this requirement. I can remember that I was forced to use `require.resolve` in other projects as well, but I never was aware of the reason.

The inconspicuous line of code which makes the difference (second config):

```
import * as dateTime from 'lib/date-time/date-time'
```

If I comment it, it works again using `'ts'`.

On my file system, the path lib/date-time/date-time.ts is located directly below ./src (which is mentioned in the resolve/root array). And it is not the first import depending on the resolve/root array.

Webpack output with error message:

```
> webpack

ts-loader: Using typescript@2.1.4 and /.../src/app/browser/tsconfig.json
ts-loader: Using typescript@2.1.4 and /.../src/browser/tsconfig.json
Hash: 5058e7029f1c0243a269161aa4ddda242a3d33a0
Version: webpack 1.14.0
Child
    Hash: 5058e7029f1c0243a269
    Version: webpack 1.14.0
    Time: 3165ms
        Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    bundle.js  283 kB       0  [emitted]  main
        + 4 hidden modules
Child
    Hash: 161aa4ddda242a3d33a0
    Version: webpack 1.14.0
    Time: 3670ms
         Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
     bundle.js  617 kB       0  [emitted]  main
    bundle.css   25 kB       0  [emitted]  main
       [0] multi main 40 bytes {0} [built]
        + 329 hidden modules

    ERROR in Cannot find module './node_modules/ts-loader/index.js'
     @ ./src/records/departure/departure.ts 2:15-49
    Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
            + 2 hidden modules
    Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
            + 2 hidden modules
    Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
            + 2 hidden modules
    Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
            + 2 hidden modules
```

Comment: May I ask whether if you change `root: ['./node_modules', './src'],` to `root: path.resolve('./src'),` will it work? (without the `require.resolve`)

Comment: It does. So it has something to do with my "root" paths. (One of the parts I did not fully understand in the Webpack docs.) Can you elaborate on why it now finds the loader?

And why it is influenced by `import * as dateTime from 'lib/date-time/date-time'` but not by all other imports without full relative/absolute paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
root: path.resolve('./src'),
```

Because the [documentation on resolve.root](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-root) states:

> The directory (absolute path) that contains your modules. May also be an array of directories. This setting should be used to add individual directories to the search path.
>
> It must be an absolute path! Don’t pass something like ./app/modules.

In addition, since [resolve.modulesDirectories](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-modulesdirectories) already has `node_modules` as the defaults, we can omit it from `resolve.root`. In other words, we don't need `root: [path.resolve('./node_modules'), path.resolve('./src'),]`

I'm not a Webpack developer but my hunch is that at every import, Webpack will change the current directory to that file so that it can resolve relative imports. During the import of the `date-time` module from `./src/records/departure/departure.ts`, it will now use the directory `./src/records/departure` and at that time it'll also need to use a loader, but because you've set the root using a relative path (`./node_modules`), it will look in `./src/records/departure/node_modules` instead. Hence giving you this error.

The above is not exactly correct but still kind of apply but here's the link to the docs: [module.loaders](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders)

> IMPORTANT: The loaders here are resolved relative to the resource
> which they are applied to. This means they are not resolved relative
> to the configuration file. If you have loaders installed from npm and
> your node_modules folder is not in a parent folder of all source
> files, webpack cannot find the loader. You need to add the
> node_modules folder as an absolute path to the resolveLoader.root
> option. (resolveLoader: { root: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules")
> })

Comment: Many thanks for your comprehensive answer. My misconception was: I did not consider the "root" array influencing loader module resolution. I expected it to be used for my source code's module resolution only.

If I understand it correctly, the "root" array is used for both finding loaders _and_ finding imports/requires in my source code. Isn't that a massive violation of the *separation of concerns* principle?

I will award you with the bounty in an hour.

Comment: Apparently, only loaders resolve relative to the resource or the parent folder of all source files (which if set as a relative path, it messes things up). I've added the link to the docs for that. I can't find anywhere why they have chosen this, so I can't say for sure whether it's wrong or not. Webpack 2 looks like it doesn't have this same problem, maybe you should take a look.